# window.location.href does not change the URL

Tags: javascript

I would like to change the URL that appears once a form has been submitted although the code below does not appear to do what I would like it to do. How do I change the URL in the address bar?

**CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XMHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-us" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <meta name="copyright" content="&copy; 2012" />
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />

    <title>sample form</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="" />

    <style type="text/css">

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var testurl = window.location.href;
        if(testurl == "file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/sample_form.html?q=test&submit=submit") {
            testurl = testurl.replace(/q=[^&]+&[a-z]+\=[a-z]+/,'test');
            alert(testurl);
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <form name="sampleform" id="sampleform" method="get" action="sample_form.html">
        <input type="text" name="q" value="" id="q" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note: because of the way you have positioned your script, you would be instantly redirected to the new url, before the page ever loaded.

Comment: @Asad = Why would it do that if I am checking whether `testurl` equates to the value in the URI?

Comment: I meant if you used KingKongFrog's solution. If you changed the value of `window.location.href` there you would be redirected before the rest of the page loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var testurl = document.URL;
    if(testurl == "file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/sample_form.html?q=test&submit=submit") {
        testurl = testurl.replace(/q=[^&]+&[a-z]+\=[a-z]+/,'test');
        window.location.href = testurl;
    }

</script>
```

A note:

> Use window.location for read and write access to the location object
>   associated with the current frame. If you just want to get the address
>   as a read-only string, you may use document.URL, which should contain
>   the same value as window.location.href

Comment: This will redirect you to the url set in testurl. I think PeanutsMonkey wants to change text in address bar only without redirect.

Comment: @KingKongFrog - Thanks. Can I use regular expressions with the `if` statement so that I don't have to hardcode the URI?

Comment: @Zefiryn - Ideally yes, that is what I want to do.

Comment: @KingKongFrog - How would I do that?

Answer (score 3):

To change the url, you have to do this :

```
window.location.href = testurl;
```

but this has the "side effect" of loading the whole page with the new url (be it or not the same).

If you want to change what appears but not reload the page, you hage to use [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to use the new HTML5 history API. That's what's done in many Ajax sites to let the URL reflect what's in the dynamically loaded page but it's not compatible with IE9-.

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "some useless title", testurl);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the users are using < IE9

Comment: So don't change the URL client-side.

Comment: I don't have access or control over the server side as it is a proprietary application that only allows changes to the client side.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: `testurl` isn't a reference to `window.location.href` (they just have the same value), so you need to assign your URL directly to `window.location.href` instead of `testurl`. For example: `window.location.href = "http://example.com/redirect.html";`

Basically, let's say that your web site was at example.com/index.html, and you wanted to redirect to example.com/redirect.html.

Your problem is occurring because you're assigning the location to `testurl`, not `window.location.href`. Let me explain:

1. `var testurl = window.location.href;` assigns the value of `window.location.href` (which is example.com/index.html) to the variable `testurl`. So at this point, `testurl` and `window.location.href` are set to example.com/index.html, but they have nothing to do with each other (`testurl` isn't a reference to `window.location.href`, it just has the same value)
2. `testurl == testurl.replace(...);` replaces `testurl` with the site you want to redirect to, but since `testurl` is *not* a reference to `window.location.href`, `testurl` becomes example.com/redirect.html and `window.location.href` stays what it was previously, which was example.com/index.html.

So in order to fix this, you need to set `window.location.href` directly, just like you would any other variable, e.g. `window.location.href = "http://example.com/redirect.html";`.

Assigning a variable to it will work in the exact same way, like so:

```
var url = "http://example.com/";
// manipulate the url variable
window.location.href = url;
```

Then, `window.location.href` will be set to whatever `url` is (which will be http://example.com/ if you didn't manipulate the variable at all)

Comment: How would you assign it directly?

Comment: just like you would any other variable. for example: `window.location.href == "http://example.com/redirect.html";`. i've edited the answer to include this.

Comment: How do you assign the value dynamically though?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean. `window.location.href` is just a string, so you can assign it to any string variable. for example:

    `var url = "http://example.com/"; 
    window.location.href = url;`

will assign http://example.com/ to `window.location.href`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution to solve your problem:

```
window.location.replace('@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")')
```