# window.location or window.location.href not changing the value in all browsers MVC application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, window

Current Url  is

http://xx.com/Home/Employee

i have cancel button in my page whenvever cancel button clicked need to navigate from different action result which is located in aother folder

**Ex: About/Result** (i.e. http://xx.com/About/Result) i have below code in my cancel function

```
function cancel() {

        window.location = '@Url.Action("Result", "About")';

        return false;
    }
```

tried all the ways like

```
window.location.href= "/About/Result"
window.location.pathname="/About/Result"
```

**but it still not changing the old value.it keeps old value only.**

referred so many links like

[window.location.href does not change the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443974/window-location-href-does-not-change-the-url)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location

but when i try to give

```
 window.location.href="http://www.google.com"
```

**it works fine**. why i can't navigate from on action to another action from different directory. any problem ?

what is the exact root cause ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found the solution by referring the following link

[windows.location.href not working on Firefox3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275092/windows-location-href-not-working-on-firefox3)

need to add return like

```
<button id="btnCancel" class="btn" onclick="return cancel()">
```

in your markup for the page, the control that calls this function on click must return this function's value.

```
function cancel() {
        window.location.href = "../../About/Index";
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Great find! This was driving me NUTS!!! During this process I also discovered that <a href="" onclick="foo()">bar</a> failed, and yet <a href="#" onclick="foo()">bar</a> worked fine. I will now cry myself to sleep upon my keyboard.

Comment: @Dave Thanks dude! I didn't realize that any value in the anchor href attribute would override whatever location you specify in your javascript.